# ¿Se puede cambiar un web panel (ya desplegado) en tomcat por el mismo pero con algunas mejoras?

Tags: java, genexus, tomcat

Buenas, estoy trabajando con Genexus Salto y tengo una aplicación ya en producción que desarrollé el año pasado con GxEvo3 update 3.  Es algo compleja, tiene integración mobile, GAM, entre algunas cosas más.
Lo que sucede es que cambié un objeto web panel (en el entorno que tengo ahora) y quiero subir únicamente ese objeto si la necesidad de desplegar toda la aplicación.
Cuando subo los .class, .js y algunos otros archivos (que veo se regeneran al tocar el web panel en la kb) al entorno de produccion e intento ver el web panel no se muestra, no hace nada.  NO logea un error tomcat, solo muestra en la pantalla un símbolo de ?.

¿Alguien ha hecho esto que intento hacer antes?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathias,

Creo que en java, si la aplicacion tiene deploy por .war, no lo puedes actualizar solo .class y .js, el tomcat reemplaza por las que tiene dentro del .war.

Hace mucho tiempo que no trabajo con java, pero hay una manera de hacer con que el tomcat no haga deploy automatico.

Espero que lo sirva...

Comment: Sandro, muy amable en responder. Para desactivar el autodeploy (lo probé y no solucionó mi problema) puedes proceder según se explica acá http://serverfault.com/questions/377407/configuring-tomcat-to-not-load-web-app-automatically-at-start-up.  Finalmente después de hacer varías prueba sin resultados tuve que recompilar toda la aplicación.  Gracias de todos modos

Answer (score 2):

todo dependera de la version de Tomcat que estas utilizando. Si mal no recuerdo, a partir de la 5.5 (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html) tenes disponible la opcion "reloadable" a nivel de Context que permite hacer eso que necesitas. Cuando lo colocas en "true", Tomcat monitorea ciertos recursos para ver si hubo cambios y cargar los nuevos. Hay bastante informacion al respecto pero en este [sitio](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-reload) esta bastante bien explicado. Ahi mismo, no dejes de leer el link que dice "why you should not use automatic reloading in a production environment".

Por ultimo, el [SAC #18043](https://www5.genexus.com/xev3/screleasenotes.aspx?S%3B178%3B94%3B1286%3B1%3B1%3BO%3B,18043;;) lo explica tambien.